# How to create a running text in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, animation, kivy

I'm trying to move a Label using the Animation library similar to a running text.

My problem is that i can move the Label from the left part of the screen to the right, but not moving it off the right part of screen and letting it move into the left part of screen.

I also cant figure out how to make an if statement with pos_hint as parameter to move the Label back to the left part of the screen.

Any help is very appreciated

Here is my code:

python-file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.animation import Animation

Builder.load_file("animation.kv")


class MyLayout(Label):
    def animate_it(self, label, *args):
        animate = Animation(
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.9},
            duration=5
        )
        animate.start(label)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv-file:

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        padding: 50
        spacing: 20

        Label:
            id: my_label
            text: "Hello World"
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.1}


        Button:
            text: "Press Me"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: .5, .5
            pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5}
            on_release: root.animate_it(root.ids.my_label)
```

EDIT: I found another (almost) solution to my problem. The problem with this is that it doesnt work very smoothly if you want the text to go over the whole length of the screen, maybe it does i dont really get the whole code to be honest

Here it is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

label = None
text = 'I was here'
text_length = len(text)
index = 0
temp_text = text + ' ' + text + ' ' + text

def update_label(dt):
    global index

    label.text = temp_text[index:index + 30]
    index += 1
    if index >= text_length:
        index = 0

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global label
        label = Label(text="???")
        Clock.schedule_interval(update_label, 0.20)
        return label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pos_hint` returns dictionary. Run this command and check pos_hint also it let you move left too:

```
def animate_it(self, label, *args):
    print(label.pos_hint)
    if label.pos_hint['center_x'] == .1:
        animate = Animation(pos_hint={"center_x": 0.9},duration=5)
        animate.start(label)
    elif label.pos_hint['center_x'] == .9:
        animate = Animation(pos_hint={"center_x": 0.1},duration=5)
        animate.start(label)
```

For start automaticly left-right moves, should use [Clock.schedule_interval](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_interval)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this solution just bounces the text from one side to the other. I want it to move letter to letter from one side of the screen and reappear on the other side. I posted an EDIT, it almost looks like this code snippet but i want it to span over the whole screen and the screen should be resizable